# The orientation of the device is returned incorrectly in iOS 8.1.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am navigating from a controller to another controller(which invokes device camera), but found that the orientation of the second controller is returned by iOS as portrait, even though I am in portrait mode.

Inititally I was on portrait mode while I was in the first controller, then tilted the device to landscape mode and navigated to the next controller(which invoked camera).

I want to perform some activity only when the orientation is landscape, so i check this condition, but the control never comes into this even when I have the device in landscape.

```
if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
  // perform an activity
}
```

Comment: How do you get the orientation? It may be that this value is being obtained "before" rotate screen.

Comment: Please put more code. It is hard to suggest something. How do you initialize your `orientation` variable? What device do you use? Do your application support landscape orientation or only portrait?

Comment: I am using

 UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation; 

I am calling this only during a tap event(while the device is in landscape mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the accurate orientation by using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` property. Click [here](http://ddeville.me/2011/01/getting-the-interface-orientation-in-ios/) for a quick comparison.